# Python List Assignment - conceptual question

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Below code generate some random data in a two-dimensional space:

First in the variable X  generate the random pairs, in the 3rd statement
  `X[50:100, :] = X1` ,assign `X1` to the positions 50 -100  - My question is , What is the Double colon for?? whether I simply put `X[50:100] = X1` is it not the same?

```
X= -2 * np.random.rand(100,2)
X1 = 1 + 2 * np.random.rand(50,2)
X[50:100, :] = X1
plt.scatter(X[ : , 0], X[ :, 1], s = 50, c = ‘b’)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try it out and see. You should look into [numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) to see how it works in more than one dimension

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the same.

Excerpt from [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays): `The value being assigned to the indexed array must be shape consistent (the same shape or broadcastable to the shape the index produces).`